# Authorize.NET CVV verification

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am using Authorize.NET PHP SDK. I have added following code to verify CVV code

```
$auth = new AuthorizeNetAIM;
$auth->amount = $amount;
$auth->card_num = $cc;
$auth->exp_date = $expiry_date;
$auth->x_card_code = $cc;
```

but now I am getting following exception:

```
Error: Uncaught exception 'AuthorizeNetException' with message 'Error: no field x_card_code exists in the AIM API.
```

How do I verify CVV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using wrong field name it's card_code not x_card_code.

```
$auth = new AuthorizeNetAIM;
$auth->amount = $amount;
$auth->card_num = $cc;
$auth->exp_date = $expiry_date;
$auth->card_code = $cc;
```